# React.js code runs in local server but not in Plunker

Tags: reactjs, plunker

I am trying to follow a simple tutorials. My test code runs perfectly in my local server. But when I try to adapt the code to Plunker, it cause an error that I couldn't figure out why. The code runs fine in Snippet. 
Maybe I miss something. Plz help. :(

```js
const Timer = ({currentValue}) => {
  return(
    <div className="Time">
      {currentValue}
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {currentValue: 150};

    setInterval(
      () => {
        this.setState({currentValue: this.state.currentValue - 1});
      }, 1000
    );
  }
// This cause an Unknown error in Plunker
  resetTimer = () => {
      this.setState({currentValue:150});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Timer currentValue={this.state.currentValue} />
        <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="react@*" data-semver="15.2.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="react@*" data-semver="15.2.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: provide the plunker link of ur code.

Comment: The plunker link:  https://plnkr.co/wi4sFLCnNU9UPKYvF9dB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ur code is proper, don't know why it is not working on `plunker`, same code is working on `Jsfiddle`, you can try this alternative, bind the `onClick` method manually, it will work, Try this:

```
const Timer = ({currentValue}) => {
  return(
    <div className="Time">
      {currentValue}
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {currentValue: 150};

    setInterval(
      () => {
        this.setState({currentValue: this.state.currentValue - 1});
      }, 1000
    );
  }
  resetTimer(){
      this.setState({currentValue:150});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Timer currentValue={this.state.currentValue} />
        <button onClick={this.resetTimer.bind(this)}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Check the Working Code on-

`plunker` code: https://plnkr.co/edit/NZPKuTdnIvL75IKgApFZ?p=preview

`jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/ypt9q7p6/

Comment: ur code was proper, check this on `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/ypt9q7p6/ . Whatever i wrote was an alternative of that. I manually bind the onClick method, arrow function used to do it for u, you don't need to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks, I got this. Describe bind(this) in the constructor works too :)

Comment: i was in hurry so just provided u a working code :), it should be defined in constructor for performance improvement, check the link how it affects the performance:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294494/react-js-and-es6-any-reason-not-to-bind-a-function-in-the-constructor