# In React is there a more standard way than this of referring to the outer class from within a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm so sorry for how badly worded that title is but I'm just learning React and I got something working in what feels like a bit of a hacky way, and I'm trying to figure it out properly.

Here's the code that I initially couldn't get to work (the removeItem part was throwing an error as this.removeItem was undefined).

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AddItem addItem={this.addItem.bind(this)} />
        <ul>
          {this.state.listItems.map(function(item,index){
              return (
                  <ListItem id={index} key={index} title={item} removeItem={this.removeItem.bind(this)} />
              );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I realised that it was something to do with scope, in that "this" inside map() was not referring to the same "this" that addItem is. The solution I came up with was just to define "this" in a separate variable for use inside the map().

```
render() {
    var theApp = this;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AddItem addItem={this.addItem.bind(this)} />
        <ul>
          {this.state.listItems.map(function(item,index){
              return (
                  <ListItem id={index} key={index} title={item} removeItem={theApp.removeItem.bind(theApp)} />
              );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

My query is - I don't feel like I've seen this kind of approach in other peoples' code or tutorials or such, but I can't quite get my head round what's going on and what would be a better way of handling this. Any thoughts, or even pointers on what to Google much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `context binding`, you need to bind the proper `context` otherwise `this` keyword (points to react component) will not be available inside `map`. You can write it like these way:

**1.** By using `arrow function`:

```
{   
    this.state.listItems.map( (item,index) => {
        return (
            <ListItem id={index} key={index} title={item} removeItem={this.removeItem.bind(this)} />
        );
    })
}
```

**2.** By using `.bind(this)` with `callback method`:

```
{   
    this.state.listItems.map( function(item,index) {
        return (
            <ListItem id={index} key={index} title={item} removeItem={this.removeItem.bind(this)} />
        );
    }.bind(this))
}
```

**Suggestion**: Instead of `binding` the events inside `render` method, you should bind them in the `constructor`, it will avoid the creation of new function during the re-rendering.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31296221/5185595

For more detail on `arrow function` check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/5185595

Answer (score 0):

You're mostly correct. However the word you're looking for is "context", not "scope".

*Scope* is how visible a variable declaration is to other code. A variable is either in the global scope, or it's scoped locally to the function in which it was called.

*Context* deals specifically with the value of the keyword `this`. `this` refers to the object that the function was called within. In React, since all of the functions are called from within the Component object, the value of `this` is typically the Component itself.

On to your workaround to the problem - it's perfectly valid and is in fact used quite often by developers. You'll often see something like `var self = this` so that the original value of `this` can easily be retained.

However, if you're coding in ES6 or using Babel or some other transpiler, you can use the ES6 "arrow function":

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AddItem addItem={this.addItem.bind(this)} />
        <ul>
          {this.state.listItems.map((item,index) => {
              return (
                  <ListItem id={index} key={index} title={item} removeItem={this.removeItem.bind(this)} />
              );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The "arrow function" does not bind a new value for `this` despite being a new function call. Instead it uses the `this` value of the context it was called in. It's very handy for situations like this; myself and other developers use it all the time, so it's quite in style.

Comment: Noting that in general you don't want to `bind` within `render` methods; handlers should either be bound in constructors or created via class properties.

Answer (score 0):

you want to keep the class context inside your map function. To make things more performant you should use a function that is pre-bound to the class in the return of your map.

```
removeItem = () => {
    ...
}
listItem = (item, index) => {
    return (
        <ListItem id={index} key={index} title={item} removeItem={this.removeItem} />
    );
}
getListItems = () => {
    return this.state.listItems.map((item,index) => this.listItem(item, index))
}
render() {
    const elems = this.getListItems();
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AddItem addItem={this.addItem.bind(this)} />
        <ul>
          {elems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

notice I use an arrow function on your class methods. this way each of those methods are pre-bound. you no longer need to call `.bind(this)` everywhere and its more performant

The arrow inline binding is available if you have enabled stage-2 or transform-class-properties in babel. If you haven't you can pre bind your functions in the constructor so that binding only needs to happen once.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    ...
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    this.listItem = this.listItem.bind(this);
    this.getListItems = this.getListItems.bind(this);
}
```