# What is the best way to call inherited method (through 'props') on ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As far as i know, there are **two main pattern** of calling **inherited method on ReactJS**, but I dont know which one should I use, or the best practice,

```
class ParentCont extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        myState : "My State"
      }
    }

    callMe() {
      console.log(this.state.myState);
    }

    render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <MyButton myProp={this.callMe.bind(this)} />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  class MyButton extends React.Component {
    buttonB() {
      this.props.myProp();
    }
    render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.props.myProp}>Click Me A</button>
          <button onClick={this.buttonB.bind(this)}>Click Me B</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<ParentCont />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

On above snippet there are **two ways** of calling the `callMe()` on `ParentCont` from `MyButton`,

**First**, attaching the `props` directly to event handler, i.e. `Click Me A` button,

**Second**, attaching so called `local function` to event handler, i.e. `Click Me B` button,

Which one is the best? or what are the advantages and drawbacks of one another?

Comment: [Click link for example: 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859154/react-js-call-parent-function-from-child)
[Example: 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-method)

Comment: You should have as many state-less components as you can. Passing down through the props is the way to go

Comment: <MyButton myProp={() => this.callMe()} />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to pass the prop function if you can. It is more efficient and less code to run. The whole point of using a local function that calls the prop function is if you want to use additional information or local information to influence the call on the function. for instance

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
    buttonB = () => {
      this.props.myProp(this.props.id);
    }
    render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.buttonB}>Click Me B</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

or if the child class has a local state for instance you would want to pass it though.

if there is no need to pass variables then you dont need the local function. notice that I removed the bind. you dont want to bind or use an inline arrow function on any handler in the render as it causes a performance hit.

Comment: do you have any reference that stated using bind and inline arrow will cause performance hit? any links maybe?

Comment: I can look it up for you if you want. or you can just do a google search. The reason why its a performance hit is because both return a new function. this is a new reference to a function as well. Which react will use to re render everything associated with said inline function. you want to use a pre-bound function so its the same function reference

Comment: If you have the reference why not, as far as i know yes we can ignore using `bind(this)` if the function that we call do not contain any `this` keyword, but we need to use `bind(this)` if we use `this` inside the function, I already tried your snippet but return an error, although you're using arrow function.

Comment: thats because you do not have the correct config for babel. you can just add the bind in your constructor to only do it once `this.buttonB = this.buttonB.bind(this)`... [I wrote another answer describing this here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43331722/2733506)

Comment: @xcode heres a few links if you really want it. https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f#9bed the eslint standard has adopted this https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Comment: I think the preferable method for me the one that use `.bind()` inside `constructor` easy to comprehend, thanks

Comment: But again **if there is no need** to pass additional information and states to the parent, isn't it more convenient to use direct `onClick={this.props.myProp}` (just like `Click Me A` button)? less typing no `bind`-ing needed, so no performance hit right?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I said in my answer :) you dont want to bind in the render. so either prebind if you need to use a function to handle the event or use a prop function that is passed if you dont need extra info