# this.state null in reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

i am just trying first something simple like only printing the this.state.validForm in the handleSubmit function, but i cant seem to access this.state.validForm. First i tried directly then with this function, but to no avail. I am new to react.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextInput from './TextInput';

class RequestForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {validForm : "false"};
        this.getInfoForm = this.getInfoForm.bind(this);
    }

    getInfoForm() {
        return this.state.validForm;
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('submit values are');
        console.log(event.target.src.value);
        console.log(event.target.email.value);
        console.log(this.state.validForm);
        console.log(this.getInfoForm());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <TextInput
                    uniqueName="email"
                    name="email"      
                    text="Email Address"
                    required={true}     
                    minCharacters={6}
                    validate="email" 
                    errorMessage="Email is invalid"
                    emptyMessage="Email is required"
                />

                <TextInput 
                    text="User"
                    name="User src"
                    required={true}
                    minCharacters={3}
                    validate="notEmpty"
                    errorMessage="Name is invalid"
                    emptyMessage="Name is required"
                />

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default RequestForm;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React ref and setState not working with ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/react-ref-and-setstate-not-working-with-es6)

Comment: Also consider pre-binding your `handleSubmit` in the same way you did with `getInfoForm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with your `render` method. Your `onSubmit` event has its own context so when you do `this.handleSubmit`, you're going to be passing the wrong context to `handleSubmit`. Simply bind `this` and you'll be set!

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
```

Or with the proposed bind operator:

```
<form onSubmit={::this.handleSubmit}>
```

Comment: *"if you have ES7 features enabled"* The bind operator is not a ES7 feature. It's still only a proposal.