# React - translating a component to ecma6 javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to translate a simple button hover example to emca6 (I'm using babel) and keep failing. I guess that my bind is wrong somehow but I'm new to jscript and don't completely understand the:

`

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);`
```

I mean I get that it's like super in python, but why the weird syntax with props passed as parameter?

```
/* non emca6 */
import React from 'react'

var HoverButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {hover: false};
    },

    mouseOver: function () {
        this.setState({hover: true});
    },

    mouseOut: function () {
        this.setState({hover: false});
    },

    render: function() {
        var label = "foo";
        if (this.state.hover) {
            label = "bar";
        }
        return React.createElement(
            "button",
            {onMouseOver: this.mouseOver, onMouseOut: this.mouseOut},
            label
        );
    }
});

React.render(React.createElement(HoverButton, null), document.body);


export default HoverButton;

/* emca6 */

import React from 'react';

class HoverButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ({hover: false});
        this.mouseOver = this.mouseOver.bind(this);
        this.mouseOut = this.mouseOut.bind(this);
    }

    mouseOver(){
        this.setState = ({hover: true});
    }

    mouseOut(){
        this.setState = ({hover: false});
    }


    render() {
        var label = "idle";
        if (this.state.hover) {
            label = "active";
        } 
        return React.createElement(
            "button",
            {onMouseEnter: this.mouseOver, onMouseOut: this.mouseOut},
            label,

        );
    }
}

export default HoverButton;
```

Comment: `this.setState = ({hover: true});` -> `this.setState({hover: true});`

Comment: Thanks that worked, but why? Are we setting the dictionary value without the equal sign because it's in a function? edit: actually it only work once and it doesn't change back to idle and shows a type undefined error on the next hover.

Comment: setState is method which came from extended React.component class. you cant define like variable. i think Alon should write an answer instead of the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do:

```
import {Component} from 'react'

class HoverButton extends Component {
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {hover: false};
    },

    mouseOver: function () {
        this.setState({hover: true});
    },

    mouseOut: function () {
        this.setState({hover: false});
    },

    render: function() {
        const label = this.state.hover ? "bar" : "foo";
        return <button 
                  onMouseOver={this.mouseOver.bind(this)}
                  onMouseOut={this.mouseOut.bind(this)}>
                  label
               </button>;
        );
    }
});
```

Notice the `bind`s on the event handlers. If you would just pass a function like `this.mouseOver`, it would have the wrong context (`this`).

Comment: I've tried the code  - after adding a closing "}" at onMouseOver. But I still get a syntax error..?

Comment: Could you pls paste the error? Possibly in the question?

Comment: Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/git/studio-branch/assets/js/index.jsx: Unexpected token (4:21)

class HoverButton extends Component {
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {hover: false};
    },

Answer (score 0):

Ok so keeping in mind that I want to write it in emca6 and the answers regarding the right way to bind our state and to assign it, I went with the following.

Although I'm still not completely sure why we bind and assign that way:

```
import {Component} from 'react'

class HoverButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = ({hover: false});
    }

    mouseOver(){
        this.setState({hover: true});
    }

    mouseOut(){
        this.setState({hover: false});
    }


    render() {
        const label = this.state.hover ? "active" : "idle";
        return React.createElement(
            "button",
            {onMouseEnter: this.mouseOver.bind(this), onMouseOut: this.mouseOut.bind(this)},
            label
        );
    }
}

export default HoverButton;
```

EDIT: So after reading this: [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)
I'm really confused on how to bind the state in the most cost efficient way. Binding it in the constructor doesn't work here.

Edit 2: So I've moved the bind back to the constructor (like it was originally) and its working now for some reason.

```
import React from 'react'
class HoverButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = ({hover: false});
        this.mouseOver = this.mouseOver.bind(this);
        this.mouseOut = this.mouseOut.bind(this);
    }

    mouseOver(){
        this.setState({hover: true});
    }

    mouseOut(){
        this.setState({hover: false});
    }

    render() {
        const label = this.state.hover ? "active" : "idle";
        return React.createElement(
            "button",
            {onMouseEnter: this.mouseOver, onMouseOut: this.mouseOut},
            label
        );
    }
}

export default HoverButton;
```

Comment: You should be able to bind in constructor using `this.mouseOver = this.mouseOver.bind(this)`. Or using class properties you can just define your handlers as fat arrow functions: `mouseOver = (event) => { }`