# React component `this` is not defined when handlers are called

Tags: reactjs

I'm attaching a simple handler in JSX. Unless I do `.bind(this)` in the JSX, when I go into the `change` method, to do `this.setState()`, `this` is `undefined`. Am I doing something wrong??

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import CounterConstants from './../constants/constants';
import AppDispatcher from './../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
import CounterActions from './../actions/actions';

class Controls extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todoText: ''
    };
  }
  change(event){
    this.setState({todoText: event.target.value});
  }
  submit(event){
    if(this.state.todoText !== ''){
      CounterActions.addTodo({text: this.state.todoText});
      this.setState({todoText: ''});
    }
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="controls form-inline">
        <input type="text" name="todoText" className="form-control" onChange={this.change.bind(this)} value={this.state.todoText} />
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.submit.bind(this)}>Add a todo</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Controls;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using es6 classes (`class Controls extends Component`), functions will not be auto-bound for you. In order to provide your functions with context, you need to bind the value of `this` to the context of your component.

If you were to use the `React.createClass`, then all functions would be auto-bound for you by default.

Most people use the constructor to bind their functions to the context of `this`. It's a little cleaner than cluttering up the JSX.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cool, for those who want more:
http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html

Thanks @Elod

Answer (score 2):

> Am I doing something wrong?

No, that's how JavaScript works. Functions are not auto-bound. The value of `this` depends on how a function is *called*. So if you pass a function somewhere but need `this` to have a specific value, you have to bind it yourself (note: *where* you bind the function doesn't matter).

Simplified example (using an object):

```js
'use strict';

var obj = {
  method() {
    console.log(this);
  },
};

var method = obj.method;
var boundMethod = obj.method.bind(obj);
method();      // undefined
boundMethod(); // Object {}
obj.method();  // Object {}
```

**Related:**

- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196)
- [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)
- [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29577977/218196)

**Documentation:**

- [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [YDKJS - `this` or That?](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md)