# this.setstate is not a function in react native

Tags: react-native

I have trouble with arrow functions in react native. When I write an arrow function, I get an error saying

> this.setstate is not a function

but when I write a regular function , I do not get any errors. Can someone tell me where is the problem. My code is below

```
var Register = React.createClass({

getInitialState : function(){

return {
ad:'',
soyad:'',
mail: '',
gcm_id:'',

},
componentWillMount: function() {
this.get_db();
},
get_db: async ()=> {     
this.setState({ mail: 'adadsasd' });    

},

})
```

Comment: Because if you write it as a regular function, React autobinds `this` for you. But since you use an arrow function that does not bind `this`, React cannot autobind `this` to refer to your component instance.

Comment: so how should i write arrow function ?

Comment: Don't use an arrow function, use a regular function.

Comment: thanks for answer andrew

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native: this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440925/react-native-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

Comment: use an es6 class and it will work, the newer versions deprecated createClass anyways so you wont be able to upgrade unless you refactor

Comment: @VaheTshitoyan This has nothing to do with that. That's with ES6 classes that don't have React autobinding. This is an ES5 component that has autobinding, but since arrow functions don't bind their own `this`, autobinding doesn't work thus `this` actually refers to `window`.