# react native _this.setState is undefined while using Picker

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

i'm using expo for my android app and trying to make a Picker.
I currently have 3 `Picker.Items` and everytime i click on one of it (to change the current Picker value), it gives me error.
I've searched for the fix, read the documentation, etc. but i still can't find my solution to this.
Here is my code

```js
state = { value: "" };
  updatePicker = val => {
    this.setState({ value: val });
  };
```

and below is my syntax inside my app class

```js
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
  onValueChange={updateValue}
>
<Picker.Item key="1" label="Test 1" value="test 1" />
<Picker.Item key="2" label="Test 2" value="test 2" />
<Picker.Item key="3" label="Test 3" value="test 3" />
</Picker>
```

this somehow gives me this error

```js
_this.setState is not a function. (In '_this.setState({ value: value})', '_this.setState' is undefined)
```

thank you in advanced

Comment: Depending on where the `updatePicker = val => {` code is located in your class you can do: `onValueChange={this.updateValue}`

Comment: @HMR tried, still gives me same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native: this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440925/react-native-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)