# React: this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a workaround for another problem I'm having but with this I got a "this.setState is not a function" error. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440925/react-native-this-setstate-is-not-a-function) answer which advises to bind it within the constructor, which I did.

This is part of my constructor:

```
this.newProject = this.newProject.bind(this);
this.openProject = this.openProject.bind(this);
this.saveProject = this.saveProject.bind(this);
```

And this is my function:

```
// Open a file, set data as session item and reload page
openProject(FileObject) {
    var read = new FileReader();
    read.readAsBinaryString(FileObject);
    read.onloadend = function() {
        //sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
        //sessionStorage.setItem("data", read.result);
        //document.location.reload();

        // Fix for missing data.
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(read.result);
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.blocks.length; i++) {
            var name = jsonData.blocks[i].name;
            var id = jsonData.blocks[i].id;
            var ip = jsonData.blocks[i].ip;
            var port = jsonData.blocks[i].port;
            this.setState( { blockCount: (i + 1), });

            // Add block to the list
            this.setState({
                blocks: this.state.blocks.concat({
                    id: id,
                    name: name,
                    ref: React.createRef(),
                    positionX: window.innerWidth*0.4  - 125 / 2,
                    positionY: 75 + ( 50 * this.state.blocks.length),
                    links:[],
                    requires: this.state.parameters.blockRequires
                })
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What would be a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` belongs to the closest function context, which in your case is `read.onloadend = function()`...NOT the class.

You can solve this problem by assigning the class-level `this` to a new variable before you enter that ad-hoc function:

```
openProject(FileObject) {
    var read = new FileReader();
    read.readAsBinaryString(FileObject);
    var that = this;
    read.onloadend = function() {
        // ...
        that.setState(/*... etc*/
```

And of course you'll want to change **all** instances of `this` within your `onloadend` callback function to `that` (or whatever variable name you choose).

*Edit: as @MDTabishMahfuz describes, you can also use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), because unlike the `function` declaration, an arrow function:

> Does not have its own bindings to `this` or `super`

Answer (score 1):

Binding this is necessary for functions of the class but you have an additional callback (`onloadend function`) which is a different function and the component's `this` is not available there.

Conventional Functions in JS have their on this in their context. You can either use the method suggested by @David784 or use an arrow function for the `onloadend` handler like so:

```
read.onloadend = () => {
    ....
    this.setState(....);
    ....
}
```

Arrow functions have this from the parent's context, that is the React component in your case.