# Cannot change parent's state from child

Tags: reactjs

Getting

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setState'
```

while trying to set parent's state from a child.

parent function:

```
setSubject(id){
 console.log(id);
 this.setState({
     currentSubject: id
});
<Subjects authToken = {this.state.authToken} subjects = {this.state.subjects} setSubject = {this.setSubject} />
```

child function:

```
const listSubjects = this.props.subjects.map(subject => {
        return(<div key={subject.id}>
                    <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target={"#" + subject.id}>{subject.title}</li>
                    <div id={subject.id} className="collapse">
                        <ul className="subject-features-list">
                            <li onClick={() => this.props.setSubject(subject.id)}>Egzamino programa</li>
                            <li>Egzaminai pagal metus</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/ :)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503559/binding-error-on-react-causing-this-state-is-undefined-with-es6/39503728#39503728, binding error with setSubject function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest Solution:

```
const newSetSubject= this.setSubject.bind(this)
<Subjects authToken = {this.state.authToken} subjects = {this.state.subjects} setSubject = {this.newSetSubject} />
```

Why you have to do this?

`this` refers to the immediate scope of the function or class whose method you are invoking, in the particular case you took the `setSubject` method from some class and gave it to another class or function to call at its own it.

At the time of invokation, as per the implementation of`setSubject`, it expects that the current scope(this will be the scope of the child function in your case) has the `setState` method.

So the gist of the problem is the scope of `this` is refering to the scope of child function.

Consider the example below:

```
class PersonComponent {
  age = 21 //default case
  render() {
    return <div> Person's age is {this.props.getAge()}</div>
  } 
 }
```

**Case 1:**

```
class Person {
  name = "John Doe"

  age  = 29
  getAge() {
    return this.a;
  }
  render() {
    return <PersonComponent getAge={this.getAge} />
  }
 }
```

In this case result will be `21`, because in the scope of the `PersonComponent`, the `age` is set at `21`.

**Case 2:**

```
class Person {
  name = "John Doe"

  age  = 29
  getAge() {
    return this.a;
  }
  render() {
    return <PersonComponent getAge={this.getAge.bind(this)} />
  }
 }
```

In this case, the result will be `Person's age is 29`, because by using `bind` you explicity created a new method which has pre-defined scope to use.