# ref is not defined using arrow function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to make a toggleable content when user clicked on outside of the element I got error of this.node is not defined error?

```
handleOutsideClick(e) {
    // ignore clicks on the component itself
    if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    }

    this.handleClick();
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={node => { this.node = node; }}>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Button handler</button>
        {this.state.visibleContent && <div>Toggle content</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Code https://codesandbox.io/s/v38q4zrq7

In the render method I've used `ref={node => { this.node = node; }}` why is it still undefined? Here's a working example that used exactly the same technique https://codepen.io/graubnla/pen/EgdgZm

Comment: Are you sure, you shared the right sandbox link

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-state-or-props-of-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503559/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-state-or-props-of-undefined/39503728#39503728)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `handleOutsideClick` is out of scope. If you're using babel, you can turn it into an arrow function directly

```
handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
    // ignore clicks on the component itself
    if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    }

    this.handleClick();
  }
```

or if that is not an option, bind it in your constructor

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}
```