# onChange event is not getting fired on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've the following events in my react component.

```
/**
 * On search change handler.
 * @param {any} e Event object
 * @memberof Login
 */
onSearchValueChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        search: e.target.value,
    });
}

/**
 * Render the token view if present.
 * @param {object} e Event object.
 */
keyPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && this.state.search !== '') {
        e.preventDefault();
        searchPackage(this.state.search).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                redirect: true,
                redirectOnSearch: true,
                searchResults: response.data,
            });
        });
    }
}
```

bound to the following input element which is a component from `react-bootstrap`.

```
<FormControl key='search' id='search' type='text' placeholder='Search Packages' value={this.state.search} onKeyDown={this.keyPress} onChange={this.onSearchValueChange} />
```

But when I try to type anything in the textbox, it only fires the `keyPress` event, but not the `onSearchValueChange`.

What am I doing wrong here? I've bind all the events in the constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-state-or-props-of-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503559/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-state-or-props-of-undefined/39503728#39503728)

Comment: I have created a demo with your code and its seems to be working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/8k3plw3818).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the `.bind(this)` to your functions. Simple way, inside the tags:

```
<FormControl ... onKeyDown={this.keyPress.bind(this)} 
 onChange={this.onSearchValueChange.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: You should `bind()` in the constructor. Alternatively, convert `onSearchValueChange` to an arrow function.

Answer (score 2):

`onChange` will be triggered only when the textbox element loses focus. You may look for the `oninput` event.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

Comment: This does not apply to React, `onChnage` is triggered on every change