# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Selected' of null on array setState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im trying to update my state which is an array by pushing new items to it but it constantly keeps failing.

```
export interface IState{
    Selected: any[]
}

export class MyComp extends React.Component<{}, IState>{
    constructor(props){
    super(props){
    this.state = {
        Selected: []
    }
 }
}

    clickevent(newItem){
        this.setState({
            Selected: [...this.state.Selected, newItem]
        })

        OR

        this.setState({
            Selected: this.state.Selected.concat(newItem)
        })

        OR

        let newArray = this.state.Selected.slice();
        newArray.push(newItem)
        this.setState({
            Selected: newArray
        })
    }
}
```

All of the above method to push data into the array by updating state results in 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Selected' of null`.

Comment: How is `clickevent` called? listener or callback? Maybe `this` refers to another object. Check it or try with an arrow function `const clickevent = newItem => { /* update state code */ }`.

Comment: you need to bind the method to the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to bind `clickevent`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props){
    this.state = {
        Selected: []
    }

    this.clickEvent = this.clickEvent.bind(this)
 }
```

Comment: oh no that's a typo. i do have a constructor. updated original post.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty alright then. Could you please update your question?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty I've updated my answer. Hope it helps you now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have your state initialised incorrectly in the constructor. Apart from this you need to `bind` `clickEvent` function so that it refers to the correct context,

```
constructor(props){
    super(props); // Super doesn't have a function body
    this.state = { // no `()` needed here since this.state is an object
        Selected: []
    }
    this.clickEvent = this.clickEvent.bind(this);
 }
```

Check this question:

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state or props' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503559/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-state-or-props-of-undefined/39503728#39503728)

Comment: fixed the state initialisation issue. still the problem is there.

Comment: clickevent(newItem){ needed to be binded

Answer (score 0):

When you update state based on previous state you should use the callback `setState((prevState) => {})` method. Like this

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    Selected: [ ...prevState.Selected, newItem]
}))
```

Here is explanation why is that from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for
>   performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.