# React - _this2.SetState is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a component that will print out input text to the screen, here is what I'm working on.

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { term: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-bar">
        <input value={this.state.term} onChange={event => this.SetState(event.target.value)} />
        The value of input is: {this.state.term}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However I keep getting an error in Chrome console:

```
bundle.js:19818 Uncaught TypeError: _this2.SetState is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```js
class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { term: '' };
    this.setInputState = this.setInputState.bind(this);
  }
  
  setInputState(event) {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-bar">
        <input value={this.state.term} onChange={this.setInputState} />
        The value of input is: {this.state.term}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to bind {event => this.SetState(event.target.value)} function to component this. problem is your onChange function not running your component this context

code should look something like this

```
const onChange = (event) => { this.setState({term:event.target.value}) }

 <input value={this.state.term} onChange={onChange.bind(this) />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to bind your this, try this (no pun intended).

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-bar">
        <input value={this.state.term} onChange={event => this.setState.bind(this, event.target.value)} />
        The value of input is: {this.state.term}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `setState`? Notice the caps

Comment: yes that's a problem too, i just copied and pasted what he had.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you had to specify what was changed in the state:

```
this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
```

instead of

```
this.setState( event.target.value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { term: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-bar">
        <input value={this.state.term} onChange={event => this.setState({term:event.target.value})} />
        The value of input is: {this.state.term}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I think you missed out on the state key name `term` and also this `SetState`, which should be `setState`. Just follow my example below am sure it will work for you also.

```
class Square extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        value: null
    };
}

render() {
  return (
  <button 
      className="square"  
      onClick={()=> this.setState({value:'X'})}>

    {this.state.value}

  </button>
  );
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { term: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-bar">
        <input value={this.state.term} onChange={event => this.SetState(event.target.value)} />
        The value of input is: {this.state.term}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

you wrote `SetState` instead of

Comment: `SetState` Instead of what?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and noticed that I was using `this.state.setState()` method instead of `this.setState()`.

Although OP's problem is the wrong capitalization.