# TypeError: _this2.props.value.forEach is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I am getting the following error while loading the below component:

```
TypeError: _this2.props.value.forEach is not a function
    fetchRecords webpack:///./src/main/js/components/forms/AutoCompanies.js?:122
    promise callback*fetchRecords webpack:///./src/main/js/components/forms/AutoCompanies.js?:115
    componentDidMount webpack:///./src/main/js/components/forms/AutoCompanies.js?:149
    React 6
    unstable_runWithPriority webpack:///./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:653
    React 5
    unstable_runWithPriority webpack:///./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:653
    React 6
AutoCompanies.js:143:24
```

And it is basically indicating this line of code   `this.props.value.forEach(e => {` in the code below. I wonder why this is happening?

I came across this post with [related error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705002/react-this2-setstate-is-not-a-function) but unable to figure out it in my context.

```
import { Select as CompanySelect } from "react-select-virtualized";

function escapeRegexCharacters(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}

const override = css`
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: red;
`;

export class AutoCompanies extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      selectedCompanyValues: null,
      selectedCompanies: [],
      loading: false,
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.companyTemplate = this.companyTemplate.bind(this);
    this.selectedCompaniesTemplate = this.selectedCompaniesTemplate.bind(this);
  }

  companyTemplate(option) {
    return (
      <div className="country-item">
        <div>{option.label}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  selectedCompaniesTemplate(option) {
    if (option) {
      return (
        <div className="country-item country-item-value">
          <div>{option.title}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return "Select Companies";
  }

  onChange = (val) => {
    this.setState({
      value: val,
      selectedCompanyValues: val,
    });
    this.props.onChange(val);
  };

  fetchRecords() {
    const loggedInUser = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("loggedInUser"));
    let url = isAdmin(loggedInUser) ? "url1" : "url2?value=" + loggedInUser.id;

    return axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        let selectedCompanies = [
          {
            title: "test",
            label: this.props.value[0] && this.props.value[0].title,
          },
        ];
        if (this.props.value) {
          this.props.value.forEach((e) => {
            selectedCompanies.push(
              response.data._embedded.companySets.filter((companySet) => {
                return companySet.companySetId === e.companySetId;
              })[0]
            );
          });
        }

        this.setState({
          selectedCompanies: response.data._embedded.companySets.map(
            (item) => ({
              label: item.title,
              title: item.title,
              companySetId: item.companySetId,
            })
          ),
          selectedCompanyValues: selectedCompanies,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchRecords(0);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CompanySelect
          value={this.state.selectedCompanyValues}
          options={this.state.selectedCompanies}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          optionHeight={60}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Added more info:

So I added following statements just below the `super(props)` in my code

```
 console.log("Props Testing");
        console.log(props);
```

And it printed like this:

```
Object { fieldName: "companySets", value: 32714, onChange: onChange(ev)
 }
​
fieldName: "companySets"
​
onChange: function onChange(ev)
​
value: 32714
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Sometimes, it is coming as an array:

```
 Object { fieldName: "companySets", value: (1) […], onChange: onChange(ev)
 }
​
fieldName: "companySets"
​
onChange: function onChange(ev)​
value: Array [ {…} ]
​​
0: Object { companySetId: 32798, sourceSystem: "12", status: "CONSENTED", … }
​​
length: 1
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Comment: Can you provide the value of the prop `value` passed by the parent component ?

Comment: It seems to me like the prop `value` is a string, and not an array. It needs to be an array to work with the `forEach` array function, we need to know the prop `value` that is being passed by the parent component like @FouadWahabi mentioned above

Comment: @FouadWahabi  : I edited my post, please let me know if that's what you were looking for. Thanks !

Comment: If `value` is the number `32714` there is indeed no `forEach` on it. `forEach` is for things like arrays.

Comment: In some cases , it is coming as an array, so I guess I would have to keep both the checks in place? I have edited my post with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've shown above, the type of `value` is a number (32714). I don't know what you're trying to accomplish in the code exactly, but a workaround to fix the error is to have the following in the if statement:

EDIT:
Since you want to be able to run the code for both when the `value` type is a number or an array, what you can do is this:

```
if (typeof this.props.value === 'number') {
    // Enter your code to run when this.props.value is a number
} else if (Array.isArray(this.props.value)) {
    // Enter your code to run when this.props.value is an array
}
```

instead of

```
if (this.props.value)
```

Comment: Thanks Nojze, In some case it is coming as an array - ( I edited my post) with this info, please let me now if your solution still remains the same?

Comment: I've updated my answer, see the new statement inside, this should work fine! :)

Comment: Thanks. In case it is not an array, I would still want to make use of the `value` which is not an array.

Comment: Umm haha okay, see my new edit in my answer then, this should work? Now it's up to you what code to run when