# React es5 vs es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been trying to learn React with Redux the past couple of weeks.  I can't seem to pass down an action as a property correctly as when I run it I get a "cannot read property "props" of null.  However finding some code online I was able to try it out using es5 syntax and it worked.  Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong in es6 and how I can make it work?  Below is my attempt at es6 which does not work with the es5 style commented out which does work.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class InputFoo extends Component {
  //export default React.createClass({

    submitHandler(evt){
    evt.preventDefault()
    const { inputFooAction } = this.props

    inputFooAction(evt.target[0].value);
  }
  //,

  render() {
    const { input } = this.props
    return (<div>
              <h1>Oh hey from inside the component {input}</h1>
              <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <input type="text" id="theInput"/>
              </form>

             </div>)
  }
}// )

//block below is commented out for es5
InputFoo.propTypes = {
  inputFooAction: PropTypes.func,
  input: PropTypes.string 
}
```

Comment: It would probably be clearer if you put the ES2015 code in one snippet and the (working) ES5 solution in another one. Also, please include where the error occurs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)

Comment: There were a lot of great answers supplied.  I really appreciate the time.  Multiple answers were correct and I chose the one who answered first as the tie breaker.  I didn't realize that I needed to attach the function to this manually.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've prepared a demo for you here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/dpRdKP

There is no autobinding ES6 classess so your `onSubmit` event needs to be handled as follows:

```
<form onSubmit={this.submitHandler.bind(this)}>
```

or even better:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this)
}
// then you can 
<form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
```

Here is the full code which demonstrates passing data from the input field found in the child component (`InputFoo`) to the parent component (`App`):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleData = this.handleData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      fromChild: ''
    };
  }

  handleData(data) {
    this.setState({
      fromChild: data
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InputFoo handlerFromParant={this.handleData} /> 
        <h5>Received by parent:<br />{this.state.fromChild}</h5>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class InputFoo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      inputField: ''
    };
  }

  submitHandler(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // pass the input field value to the event handler passed
    // as a prop by the parent (App)
    this.props.handlerFromParant(this.state.inputField);

    this.setState({
      inputField: ''
    });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      inputField: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <input type="text" 
                 id="theInput" 
                 value={this.state.inputField} 
                 onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <h5>Visible in child:<br />{this.state.inputField}</h5>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to bind `this` of the component to your event handler. There 3 ways to do it with ES6:

```
//most effient way 
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
}
OR
submitHandler = (e) => {....}
OR
render(){
     ...
      <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler.bind(this)}>
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using es2015 classes in React, you need to manually bind `this` to your class methods. You can do it in your constructor(which is [recommended](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding)):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
}
```

or when setting your handler to your `onSubmit` prop:

```
<form onSubmit={this.submitHandler.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: you should not do it in render method in general.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must call the *super* inside the constructor like this.
This is made inside your class

`constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }`

After that you may be able to use *this.props.myProperty*

Hope it works

Comment: so I did try this earlier and that didn't do it.  One of the below questions did though.  Thanks for the input and time though!

Answer (score 0):

With es2016, you need to manually bind `this` to your class method like :

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
}
```

handler on form

```
<form onSubmit={this.submitHandler.bind(this)}>
```