# How unperformant are anonymous functions in React component attributes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anonymous-function

You're not supposed to use anonymous functions in react attributes, e.g.

```
<a onClick=()=>doIt('myId')>Aaron</a>
```

I understand why this creates a performance problem for React's reconciliation because that anonymous function is recreated on every render pass and will thus always trigger a real DOM re-render of some kind.  My question is, for a small component (i.e. not table where every row has a link) is this insignificant?  I mean, React is smart enough just to replace the handler, not to re-render the DOM, right? so the cost is not that high?

Comment: doIt('myId')>Aaron is not precisely an anonymous functions

Comment: Although the syntax is slightly wrong, there is indeed an anonoymous function for the onClick prop. It should look like this: `<a onClick={()=>doIt('myId')}>Aaron</a>`

Comment: @CpnAhab, does [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42308008/1333836) solve your question?

Answer (score 9):

I feel obliged to inform you that using an `Anonymous function` and `Function.bind(this)` in the render triggers a new render. This is because both

```
doIt.bind(this, 'myId') === doIt.bind(this, 'myId') // false

AND

() => doIt('myId') === () => doIt('myId') // false
```

are FALSE!

If you want to bind something to a function, use partial application with a method in the React class.

```
class myComponent extends Component {

  doIt = (id) => () => {
    // Do Something
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <a onClick={this.doIt('myId')}>Aaron</a>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: using arrow functions inside class are translated under the hood to a property of that class so inhereted instances are creating a new property of the same function, but when using a normal class method like doIt() {}, it will be added to class prototype which will be shared among the instance of that class, that's why I think using arrow functions would affect the performance in a negative way for some use cases. 
and here is a link for explaining that https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1

Comment: This answer contains the **WHY**!! Using arrow function leads to **re-rendering** the component and its children. Thanks for the answer. Just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

For:

- small components: you are ok (almost no performance issues)
- large components: the deeper you get the more try to avoid it

In [React documentation about event handling](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), you can find:

> In most cases, this is fine. However, **if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering**. We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.

---

Note: React is not handling callback props differently than other props. It always compares the old and new prop. Thus it re-renders when anonymous function is present because the anonymous function is always newly created.

Answer (score -1):

Your JSX code sample should actually look like this:

```
<a onClick={ ()=>doIt('myId') }>Aaron</a>
```

Using an anonymous fat arrow function like this is perfectly valid. You **are** supposed to use anonymous functions in react attributes. **That's okay**.

Yes, it's **not a best practice**. If you want to solve [the `this` context issue when using the ES6 class extends React.Component syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41272784/1333836) I would advise you to bind the function in the class constructor.

No, for a 'small' component (i.e. not table where every row has a link) this is not a significant performance issue. You are safe.