# Reactjs this.setState is not a function error

Tags: reactjs

Im novice to React js, i don't know whats wrong with below code, but i'm getting setState is not a function error.Please help me to fix this.

```
class AppBarLayout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        visibleSideBar:true,
        slide:""
      }
  }
  showProfile(){

    this.setState({
        slide:'slide'
    });
    console.log(this.state.slide);
  }
  render(){
    return(
            <div>
        <header>
          <NavBar show={this.showProfile}/>
          <Profile slide={this.state.slide} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AppBarLayout;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to bind `this.showProfile` in the component constructor

`this.showProfile = this.showProfile.bind(this)`

More detail about this on the *Handling Events* page of the React doc : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on [Delapouite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232943/delapouite)'s answer if you don't like to bind every function in the constructor you can use arrow functions to automatically bind to the correct context.

For example:

```
class AppBarLayout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        visibleSideBar:true,
        slide:""
      }
  }

  // Now showProfile is an arrow function
  showProfile = () => {
    this.setState({
        slide:'slide'
    });
    console.log(this.state.slide);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <header>
          <NavBar show={this.showProfile}/>
          <Profile slide={this.state.slide}/>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AppBarLayout;
```

Comment: Be careful using this syntax, it is not standard (yet) and needs a specific Babel transformation.

Comment: Yup, although it's getting [quite there](http://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20functions)

Comment: I know this is a few years old now, but has this become standard now? I'm new to React and want to learn the best practices.   I like how this is more terse and flexible so I hope it is the standard.

Comment: It's most likely that it will land in JavaScript, as it is in stage 3: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I solved the problem without binding.

Declaring the method like this was generating the error:

```
  async onSubmit(e) {
     event.preventDefault();
     this.setState({ shopEthereumAddress: e.target.id });
  }
```

The CORRECT declaration which will not generate the error is this:

```
onSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ shopEthereumAddress: event.target.id });
}
```

This works.

Answer (score 3):

```
toggleSwitch() {
    this.setState({
        name: 'Ram ji'
    });
}
```

Using an arrow function keeps the context of `this` set to the parent scope. The main benifit of arrow functions apart from being more concise is

> Main benefit: No binding of ‘this’

```
// use this arrow function instead of
toggleSwitch = () => {
    this.setState({
        name: 'Ram ji'         //It's working
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the arrow function make it work? Because it keeps the context of `this` instead of it's own closure context

Comment: you save my day :)

Comment: Thanks Amir Farahani