# How can I avoid is not a function error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a switch statement in my reactJs application in ES6 mode. I have this statement:

```
switch (hoera) {
        case 'one':
            return this.runThis();
            break;
        default:
}

runThis(something)
{
        ..
}
```

The chromeconsole-error is :

```
TypeError: this.runThis is not a function
```

So runThis is a method defined on my component. Seems to work outside of a switchstatement though.

Comment: Why don't you add `console.log(this, this.runThis)` so you find what it _is_.

Comment: You need to provide more context. But I guess it's a duplicate of [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29577977/218196)

Answer (score 1):

'this' does not refer to your component instance  inside of your function containing the `switch` statement.

you could inside the constructor add `this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this)` where `myFunction` is the function containing the switch statement.

Here is a good article about more ways to handle `this` inside of react : https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56#.gdmm0mob8

And here is some documentation about `bind` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: I actually think its not the `runThis` that needs to be bound, but the function that has the switch in it (which isn't shown).

Comment: *"Inside the switch statement this is loosing its binding to the class."* That part is wrong.