# React - Cannot read property 'setState' of null

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm aware theres similar threads that discuss the scoping issue.

Using the following component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Example extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        }
    }

    addMore() {
        this.setState({
            counter: this.state.counter + 1
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div onClick={ this.addMore }>
                <p>counter: { this.state.counter }</p>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

When you click the `div` you get `Cannot read property 'setState' of null`

I'm aware you can do things like `this.addMore.bind(this)` but all this seems weird extra boilerplate style code just to make it work.

---

What is considered the most elegant way to do this? As surely people must have a preferred way which have their benefits, other than being an eye sore?

Comment: The class properties proposal is probably the most elegant solution, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34050078/218196 .

Comment: http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Answer (score 21):

```
addMore = () => {
  this.setState({
    counter: this.state.counter + 1
  });
}
```

the arrow syntax takes care of the `this` binding for you

Check this great link for more information, it shows many ways to accomplish this
http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html

Comment: This is not valid ES6 though.

Comment: Why so, Felix??

Answer (score 9):

You need to bind the correct `this` context to the function, and you can do that by adding `this.addMore = this.addMore.bind(this);` to the constructor function.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        counter: 0
    }

    this.addMore = this.addMore.bind(this);
}
```

In the ES5 React.createClass all functions were automatically bound to the correct `this` but in ES6 class the correct `this` context isn't automatically bound. [reference](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

This is called Bind in Constructor and this is the approach currently recommended in the React docs for “better performance in your application”. [reference](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)