# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to child to parent communication so, i'm using props. There's have a little problem. I get an error when I use the StatusChanged() function.

There is my parent (App.JS) file:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { trackingStatus: true };
  }

  trackingStatusUpdate(data)
  {
      console.log(data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switcher trackingStatus={this.state.trackingStatus} trackingStatusUpdate={this.trackingStatusUpdate} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And There is my child (Switcher.JS) file:

```
class Switcher extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            trackingStatus: this.props.trackingStatus
        };
    }   


    statusChanged()
    {
        this.props.trackingStatusUpdate(this.state.trackingStatus);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Tracking Mode</h3>
                <label className="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.trackingStatus} onChange={this.statusChanged}  id="switch"  />
                  <div className="slider round"></div>
                </label>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

Switcher.defaultProps = {
    trackingStatus: true
}
```

What is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Embed your code in the question instead of giving a link to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)

Comment: @ShammelLee i did it, thank you.

Comment: @AndrewLi i saw this question but it is not same.

Comment: @Rys It *is* the same. The answer is the same and the reason is to. Please read it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `trackingStatusUpdate()` and `statusChanged()` class methods…

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {trackingStatus: true};

    this.trackingStatusUpdate = this.trackingStatusUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  ...
}

class Switcher extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {trackingStatus: this.props.trackingStatus};

    this.statusChanged = this.statusChanged.bind(this);
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Rys my pleasure. Glad I could help :)