# Form errors with handleInputChange in component

Tags: reactjs, this

I'm using map to loop over an array of objects. I'm using this data to populate a form however I'm having trouble with the `handleInputChange` function. How do I initiate `handleInputChange` when I'm using a components. The error I get is `this.setState is not a function at handleInputChange`

Path: `formComponent.jsx`

```
   return (
      <li>
        <SingleInput
          inputType={'text'}
          title={'Company name'}
          name={'position.company'}
          controlFunc={this.props.handleInputChange}
          content={this.props.company}
          placeholder={'Company name'}
          bsSize={null}
        />

      </li>
    );

CareerHistoryPositionsUpdateForm.propTypes = {
  company: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  controlFunc: PropTypes.string
};
```

Path: `form.jsx'

```
handleInputChange(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
  const name = target.name;

  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
}

renderPositions() {
  const profileCandidateCollection = this.props.profileCandidate;
  const careerHistoryPositions = profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.careerHistoryPositions;
  if (careerHistoryPositions) {
    return careerHistoryPositions.map((position) => {

      return (
        <CareerHistoryPositionsUpdateForm
          key={position.uniqueId}
          company={position.company}
          controlFunc={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      )
    })
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <form className="careerHistoryForm" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
      <ul>
        <p>Test</p>
        {this.renderPositions()}
      </ul>

      <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) `handleInputChange` to the instance of the component so [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) inside the function references the expected object when it's called:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
  }
}
```

---

If you're using [`babel-preset-stage-2`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) (or using tooling which configures the necessary Babel plugin for you, such as [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)), you can use this [slightly nicer syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) to bind the function when you're defining it:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: hmmm. I'm getting this error `You provided a 'value' prop to a form field without an 'onChange' handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use 'defaultValue'. Otherwise, set either 'onChange' or 'readOnly'. Check the render method of 'FormControl'.`

Comment: Sorry, not sure what I've changed but the error has disappeared. Now I can't type in the input field and there are no errors in console.

Comment: You are providing value to an input but you are not providing an onChange handler to that input. That's why react is giving that warning. According to this warning, that input type is in FormControl component.

Comment: Thanks Ritesh, if I `console.log(this.state);` at the end of `handleInputChange` I can see it changing adding the last letter. It only allows 1 character.