# When running this._login `this.navigation`is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to navigate inside the function `_login` rather than inline. In the function `this.props.navigation` is `undefined`. What's wrong there?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Form, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Button, FormValidationMessage, FormLabel, FormInput } from 'react-native-elements';
import { AgendaScreen } from './AgendaScreen';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Please sign in',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
        <FormInput onChangeText={this.inputChanged} />
        <FormValidationMessage>{'This field is required'}</FormValidationMessage>
        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
        <FormInput secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={this.inputChanged} />
        <FormValidationMessage>{'This field is required'}</FormValidationMessage>
        <Button raised onPress={this._login} title="Sign in" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  inputChanged() {
    console.log('adfasdf');
  }

  _login() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Agenda');
    console.log('Logging in');
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  }
});

export default StackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Agenda: AgendaScreen
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `_login` method to your class:

```
<Button raised onPress={this._login.bind(this)} title="Sign in" />
```

Or declare `_login` method as arrow function:

```
 _login = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Agenda');
    console.log('Logging in');
  }
```

Comment: Ah, super! I get the good old `bind` but I need to read up on the meaning of arrow functions in react.

Comment: Arrow functions haven't own context, so you don’t need to change context of this in callbacks and create wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

When passing `_login` down to your `Button` component you lose the value of `this`.

The solution would be to bind `this` to `_login`, for example, inside the `constructor`:

`this._login = this._login.bind(this);`

Or you can use `Arrow functions` :

```
<Button raised onPress={() => { this._login() }} title="Sign in" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are trying to use `this` inside a function that will be called by another component/function (`Button`).

That `Button` doesn't know `this` because it's not in the same context.

You need to bind the method to the current object.

To do this, I recommend to bind it in the constructor.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this._login = this._login.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {/* MORE CODE */}
                <Button raised onPress={this._login} title="Sign in" />
            </View>
        );
    }

    // * MORE CODE *
}
```

Secondly, this should be done in the constructor instead of inline.

If it's done inline, then a **NEW** function is assigned to `onPress` and react will re-render that part without needing to.

The same happens with inline arrow functions.

**EDIT**

This second part only applies when:

1. Using `PureComponent`
2. Using `shouldComponentUpdate` to match the props

However, inline you are creating a different function each time react renders the component. Still bad practice.

**EDIT 2 (ES6)**

To prevent using a `constructor` you could use arrow functions but in a different way. Like [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16879).

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  doWork = () => {
    // doing some work here.
  }

  render() {
    return <Text onPress={this.doWork}>Do Some Work</Text>
  }

}
```

This way you are creating the function only once per lifetime.