# _this3.state.method is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding, es6-class

I have a .js file as such:

My Class Component:

```
[...]
constructor(props, context) {
    [...]
    this.method1 = this.method1.bind(this);
}

anotherMethod() {
    [...]
    this.state.method1();
}

method1() {
    //Do something
}
```

I am getting this error: _this3.state.method1 is not a function. I tried following some other known solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler).

I have a few questions:

1. What is the root cause?
2. What is _this3 an where did it come from?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I found the solution which is to remove the "state". Instead of `this.state.method1()`, it should be `this.method1()`. Just curious how come i do not need the "state" when i bind it above?

Comment: It seems you are not aware of what `state` is in `React` context. I recommend you to read more about development pattern in `React`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `method1` not in `state`, This is component self function, Unless `method1` in `state` like the following.

```
this.state = {method1:() =>{ /*Do something*/ }}
```

You can read `React` website about [`state`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and [`Handling Events`](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).