# TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageList' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a random list of images from an array of images defined in state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import card1 from '../graphics/card1.jpg';
import card2 from '../graphics/card2.jpg';
import card3 from '../graphics/card3.png';
import card4 from '../graphics/card4.jpg';
import card5 from '../graphics/card5.png';
import card6 from '../graphics/card6.png';

class BoardGame extends Component {
    state = { 
        imageList: [card1,card2,card3,card4,card5,card6],
        board: this.chooseImages(2,2)
    }
```

this is the function that suppose to return the new array:

```
//choose random images at half size of board
        let data=[];
        let selectedImage;
        let imageList = this.state.imageList;
        const numOfPics=(rows*columns)/2;
        for(let i=0;i<numOfPics;i++){
           selectedImage = imageList[Math.floor(Math.random()*imageList.length)]
            data.push(selectedImage,selectedImage);
        }
        data=this.shuffleImageList(data);
        return data;
    }
```

'TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageList' of undefined' error point  on

```
let imageList = this.state.imageList;
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are you binding this to your class method?

Comment: and you don't need to add imageList to state as it isn't dynamic.

Comment: choosImages is within the class if that's what you meant.
and moving the imagesList out of the state did fixed the problem.
Still wondering what was the problem

Comment: As @eramit2010 mentioned, you need to bind function to your class, Then you can access state. In other way, instead of creating array in state and initialising with imported image, you can initialise imageList as an array. i.e `let imageList = [card1, card2, ...];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)

Answer (score -1):

So it looks like you haven't initialized local state in the constructor. if you're using state in a component you need to initialize state in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    imageList: [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6],
    board: this.chooseImages(2,2)
  }
}
```

without initializing state in the constructor you don't have access to it from state in your component. As Sameer said without this you need to declare it using let

Comment: OP's syntax is actually valid. It is called class field declarations and is a ecmascript proposal. Babel transpiles that into what you just wrote.

Comment: Interesting, so then from my understanding I need to by using babel 7.0.0 or higher for this to take effect? Also this seems really convenient and would make for clearer code

Comment: Yeah, many people seem to prefer it. I'm not so keen on it though.