# Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the values ​​from the input in the button click but when I click the error appears: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined.

This my code, in authentication function this.state returns: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    email: '',
    pass: ''
  }
}

handleChange (event) {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  })
}

authentication() {
 console.log(this.state);
}

render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <LoginStyles />
                <main>
                    <section>
                        <h2 className="title">Login</h2>

                        <div className="form__login">
                            <label>Nome:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)} />

                            <label>Senha:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="pass" onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)} />

                            <button className="btn-default" onClick={this.authentication}>Acessar</button>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </main>
            </Fragment> 
        )
    }
```

Comment: use `onClick={this.authentication.bind(this)}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler

Comment: Or: bind it once in the constructor rather than on every render.

Comment: Use if ( typeof variable == "Number" | "String" | "Object" ) to validate variable before use if there is a chance it could be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind your authentication function as well as handleChange function. To do that you can either use bind method in constructor or use ES6 arrow operator as below-

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  })
}

authentication = () => {
 console.log(this.state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone already mentioned, you have to bind the method in the constructor or in the onClick as he did

Here is a link to [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) in React