# Cannot read property 'state' of undefined solv

Tags: reactjs

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!

In the onFormSubmit() I get error:
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined.
Why does converting the onFormSubmit to an arrow function below solve the problem?
In stackoverflow, the url :[Cannot read property 'state' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181666/cannot-read-property-state-of-undefined)

STATED HOW TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:
As someone already mentioned, you have to bind the method in the constructor or in the onClick as he did

What does bind the method means in simple terms?

```
   onFormSubmit = event => {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log(this.state.term);
```

}

Why does this other way also works:

```
 <form onSubmit={event => this.onFormSubmit(event)} className="ui form">
            <div className="field">
```

SearchBar.js

```
                import React from 'react';

            class SearchBar extends React.Component {

               state = { term: '' };


               onFormSubmit(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log(this.state.term);
               }


                render() {
                return (
                <div className="ui segment">
                    <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
                    <div className="field">
                        <label>Image Search</label>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.term} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ term: e.target.value.toUpperCase()})} />
                    </div>
                    </form>

                </div>);
                }
            }

            export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is `this` is undefined in `onFormSubmit` function why? because `onFormSubmit` has not been registered as `SearchBar` property. to solve either bind (onclick or in the constructor) or change your function into arrow function..... why arrow functions auto binds read about that in [here](https://medium.com/@joespinelli_6190/using-arrow-functions-to-avoid-binding-this-in-react-5d7402eec64).
And also add constructor to your class and call the `super()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)} className="ui form">
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, turning the method into an arrow function `bind`s it to `this` instance of the component. Binding is simply giving the function a context.

Where you use `this.state` and `this.props`, for example in your `render` method, the `this` part is referring to the current instance of your component. If `render` wasn't automatically bound to the component instance, you would not be able to use `this`.

You'll see `this` used a lot in React class components, but you will encounter it outside of React as well, as it's just a generic way for a Javascript class instance to refer to its own properties and methods.