# React this.setState not working with context API

Tags: reactjs

Currently I have this code from my AppContext.js file

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

export const AppContext = createContext();

export class AppProvider extends Component {

state = {
    test: '',
};

getEntries() {
    console.log('FIRED');

    this.setState({test: 'HELLO'});
}

render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider
          value={{
              ...this.state,
              getEntries: this.getEntries
          }}
      >
          {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
}

}
```

I'm calling the getEntries function and its displaying message from the console successfully but the this.setState is not working it says TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)

Comment: `getEntries` doesn't know about `this` yet, you have to bind it in the constructor.

Comment: `getEntries = () => { ... }` (bind it to `this`)

Comment: binding this also works..thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is `this` is not bound to the right context.

The simplest workaround is probably to use this syntax:

```
getEntries = () => {
    ...
}
```

There are several ways in React to bind `this` to the class context: [check this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) for other ways.

Comment: I have used your suggestion arrow function in class property . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

getEntries function needs to be bind to the component. The simple way to do it is to use arrow function as shown below.

```
getEntries = () => {
    console.log('FIRED');

    this.setState({test: 'HELLO'});
}
```

The second way to bind getEnteries method to the component is

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.getEntries = this.getEntries.bind(this);
  }
```