# Uncaught TypeError: this.handleSearchNext is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I am attempting to override a keyEvent for a handsontable.
The code runs but will get the error 
"Uncaught TypeError: this.handleSearchNext is not a function"
But it is a function defined, so I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

```
async componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    this.hotTable.updateSettings({
      afterDocumentKeyDown(e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          this.handleSearchNext(e)
          e.stopPropagation()
          console.log('Stopped propigation in table', e)
        }
      }
    })
}
.
.
.
handleSearchNext = (e) => {...}
```

Comment: You have to bind method to `this`: in the constructor: `this.handleSearchNext = this.handleSearchNext.bind(this);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I thought since it was an arrow function it doesnt need to be specifically bound. Doesn't ()=> automatically bind the function?