# d3.js + react.js --> cant access the state

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, state

could someone please tell me why I cant access the react.state in my d3.js function.
I really cant figure out why.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3';

class Treemap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      test: 1
    }
this.drawTreeMap = this.drawTreeMap.bin(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.drawTreeMap();
    console.log(this.state.test) // works fine
  }

  drawTreeMap() {
    Promise.all([
      d3.json("https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/tree_map/kickstarter-funding-data.json"),
      d3.json("https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/tree_map/movie-data.json"),
      d3.json("https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/tree_map/video-game-sales-data.json")
    ])
    .then(function(data) {
      let kickstarter = data[0];
      let movie = data[1];
      let videoGamesSaleData = data[2];

      console.log(this.state.test)  // does not work (Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'state' of undefined)
```

The first `console.log(this.state.test)` in the lifecycle method works, but the second one does not work.
Is it because d3 does not cooperate with react state, or did i make a foolish mistake?

Best regards!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access React instance (this) inside event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577977/unable-to-access-react-instance-this-inside-event-handler)

Comment: You need to bind `this` to your `drawTreeMap()` function inside your constructor. `this.drawTreeMap = this.drawTreeMap.bind(this);`

Comment: Binding this in the constructor does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to return the Promise respond, as you can see on example : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
let promis = Promise.all([
      d3.json("https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/tree_map/kickstarter-funding-data.json"),
      d3.json("https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/tree_map/movie-data.json"),
      d3.json("https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/tree_map/video-game-sales-data.json")
    ])
    .then(function(data) {
      return data;
    });

console.log(promis[0]);
console.log(this.state.test)
```