# Cannot read property 'value' when simulating a form submit

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to do a complete istanbul coverage test with jest. At this moment I have a component almost all tested but there is a handleSubmit function where I make a dispatch receiving form event data and when I run the test it tells me

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

      10 |             payload: {
      11 |                 name: name.value,
    > 12 |                 item: item.value, 
         |                            ^
      13 |                 status: status.value  }
      14 |         })
      15 |     }
```

I am loading a mockstore, mounted all the component, its all tested but the submit still fails. My test function is as simple as:

```
it('testing submit', () => {
const form = component.find(`[data-test="submit"]`).first()
form.simulate('submit')
... and continues expecting some existences, but there aren't problems there
```

I already tried this: [enzyme simulate submit form, Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295768/enzyme-simulate-submit-form-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

And tried to parse the event values in the simulate action...

The complete module code is...

```
class Filters extends Component {
    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const {name, items, status} = event.target;
        this.props.dispatch({
            type: 'SEARCH_PLAYER',
            payload: {
                name: name.value,
                item: item.value, 
                status: status.value  }
        })
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} data-test="submit">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-12 text-center"> ...
```

Another really crazy thing is that my test recognize the "event.target.name.value" and not the items and status. In fact if i delete items and status from the dispatch the test runs successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using `item` on line 12, but extracting `items` from the `event.target`.

Answer (score 2):

The way you chose to handle values is a bit strange. Instead, handle values through `state` like so: [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Then you can test that `this.props.dispatch()` was called with the correct values.

Side note: Avoid using `data` attributes when unnecessary, as they'll start to clog up your `DOM` with superfluous attributes. You have plenty of options to `find` by `element`, `element.className`, `className`, ...[and so on](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html).

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/5j4474rkk (you can run the test defined below by clicking on the `Tests` tab at the bottom left of the screen.

**components/Form/Form.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    test: ""
  };

  static propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: "SEARCH_PLAYER",
      payload: {
        test: this.state.test
      }
    });
  };

  render = () => (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form-container">
      <h1>Form Testing</h1>
      <input
        className="uk-input input"
        type="text"
        name="test"
        placeholder="Type something..."
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={this.state.test}
      />
      <button type="submit" className="uk-button uk-button-primary submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**components/Form/__tests__/Form.js** (`shallowWrap` and `checkProps` are custom functions that can be found in `test/utils/index.js`)

```
import React from "react";
import { shallowWrap, checkProps } from "../../../test/utils";
import Form from "../Form";

const dispatch = jest.fn();

const initialProps = {
  dispatch
};

const initialState = {
  test: ""
};

const wrapper = shallowWrap(<Form {...initialProps} />, initialState);
describe("Form", () => {
  it("renders without errors", () => {
    const formComponent = wrapper.find(".form-container");
    expect(formComponent).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it("does not throw PropType warnings", () => {
    checkProps(Form, initialProps);
  });

  it("submits correct values to dispatch", () => {
    const name = "test";
    const value = "Hello World!";
    const finalValues = {
      type: "SEARCH_PLAYER",
      payload: {
        [name]: value
      }
    };

    wrapper.find("input").simulate("change", { target: { name, value } }); // simulates an input onChange event with supplied: name (event.target.name) and value (event.target.value)

    wrapper
      .find(".form-container")
      .simulate("submit", { preventDefault: () => null }); // simulates a form submission that has a mocked preventDefault (event.preventDefault()) to avoid errors about it being undefined upon form submission

    expect(dispatch).toBeCalledWith(finalValues); // expect dispatch to be called with the values defined above
  });
});
```