# Should I use a controlled React component for the input field (security wise)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a React controlled component for the password input field:

```
onPasswordChange(ev) {
  this.setState({
    passoword: ev.target.value
  });
}

<input
  value={this.state.password}
  onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
>
```

As you can see in the image below if the component is controlled we can see the password value if I go and inspect the element. My question is: Is this the right way to control a password input? (security wise).

[image]

I know that I can use the ref={} on the input field but I want to know the best practices on handling password fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an interesting question but I don't think it's really a problem. From my knowledge, I think that you could always access the value of the input field if you have access to the inspector by using `document.getElementById('passwordInputId').value` for example. The password type is set so that someone behind you can't see what you are writing. [This is a good example of what I'm talking about](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2417).

So you should probably use the controlled component with the state, since it's the way recommended by React and it's better to [avoid refs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29504636/6499571).

Comment: Thank you for the answer @César Landesa!