# How to toggle multiple class in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have one question, how to use multiple toggle class

Please check my example below

I want to click `<TaxItem />` and add some class to that element, and the second click to remove that class

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TaxItem from "./TaxItems/"
import Pentagon from "../../../assets/images/pentagon.png"

class Taxs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      taxStatus: false
    }
    this.handleTaxStatus = this.handleTaxStatus.bind(this);
  }

  handleTaxStatus(element) {
    console.log('sdasa', element)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="taxs">
        <TaxItem
          image={Pentagon}
          name='Item 1'
          taxStatus={false}
          handleTaxStatus={this.handleTaxStatus(this)}
        />
        <TaxItem
          image={Pentagon}
          name='Item 2'
          taxStatus={false}
          handleTaxStatus={this.handleTaxStatus(this)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Taxs
```

And here you can check button where I have onClick:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class TaxItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tax-item" onClick={this.props.handleTaxStatus}>
        <div className={this.props.taxStatus ? 'checked on' : 'checked'}><i className="icon icon-check"></i></div>
        <img src={this.props.image} alt="Pentagon" />
        <p>{this.props.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TaxItem
```

How I can use THIS, something like jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add/Remove class to parent DOM element React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364174/add-remove-class-to-parent-dom-element-react-js)

Comment: Yes, but I have one button to click

Comment: Hello!.. First, you should fix your example by creating a functional one, instead of just putting the two React Components implementation.. :)
Anyways, if you want to add the class to just the clicked `TaxItem`, then you need a `taxStatus` property for each one of them, and pass a different `taxStatus` to each `TaxItem`. 
Using "this" would lead to modifying the DOM directly, which in this case, can avoided

Comment: @BorisCivcic The ref does. Just try at your end and ask again if you're not able to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, I would suggest you to not use "THIS", which would mean use the refs, because it would lead to edit the DOM directly, which in React should be avoided when you can.

Instead, you could use an array of `taxStatus` property, one for each `TaxItem`, and using them as toggle, something like in the following:

```js
class TaxItem extends React.Component {
    localHandleClick = (_) => {
            this.props.handleClick(this.props.taxStatusIndex);
        };
    
    render() {
        const {taxStatus, handleClick} = this.props;
        
        return (
            <div
                className={"button" + (taxStatus ? " checked" : " not-checked")}
                onClick={this.localHandleClick} />
        );
    }
}

class Taxs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        const taxItemCounter = props.num;
        
        this.state = {
            taxesStatus: new Array(taxItemCounter).fill(false)
        }
    }
    
    handleClick = (i) => {
        const taxesStatus = this.state.taxesStatus;
        taxesStatus[i] = !taxesStatus[i];
        
        this.setState({taxesStatus});
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.taxesStatus.map((status, index) => 
                        <TaxItem
                            key={index}
                            taxStatusIndex={index}
                            handleClick={this.handleClick}
                            taxStatus={status} />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Taxs num={3} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button.checked {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Anyways, if you DO want to use "THIS" (which again, would mean using the refs), I can provide you an example.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how much I will have TaxItem. I need to add for each [0],[1]?

Comment: I've edited the snippet: sooner or later you will now how many TaxItem you will have (probably because of a prop that you pass to `Taxs` Component. In the snippet, I pass a prop called `num`, and based on that, I create an array of desired length, and also the `render()` changes, as you can see, rendering `num` `TaxItem`

Comment: I've edited again the snippet to avoid arrow function inside the `render()` method

Comment: Thank you, that's it! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Though, the solution might not be the best. One question: is it mandatory that `Taxs` Component knows the state of the button? Because you could have `taxesStatus` directly inside the `TaxItem` Component